# How to get content of ScrolledText?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to get content of a ScrolledText but so far success is not with me :)
I don't understand where i'm wrong.
Here a very simple example of not working code...

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from ScrolledText import ScrolledText


def returnPressed(value):
    print "CONTENT: " + value


root = Tk()
st = ScrolledText(root)
st.bind("<Return>", lambda event, i=st.get("1.0", "end-1c"): returnPressed(i))
st.insert("insert", "TEST")
st.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is because of lambda definition.
By this way, function is created with constant "i" value, which is the value at declaration of function.

By rewording lambda as it, it works!

```
st.bind("<Return>", lambda event: returnPressed(st.get("1.0", "end-1c")))
```

Comment: It is not because of lambda definition: default parameters are evaluated when the function declaration is evaluated

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the value at the time you create the button, which means the value will always be empty.  You need to get the value at the time that the event is processed.

You should avoid using lambda, it is a somewhat advanced concept that in this case adds complexity without adding any value. Simply get the value from within the function:

```
def returnPressed(event):
    value = event.widget.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print "CONTENT: " + value
...
st.bind("<Return>", returnPressed)
```